# How to find which annotation send showDetails?

Tags: iphone, mkpinannotationview

How to find which annotation send showDetails?

```
MKPinAnnotationView* customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                             initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:BridgeAnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
            customPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
            customPinView.animatesDrop = YES;
            customPinView.canShowCallout = YES;

            // add a detail disclosure button to the callout which will open a new view controller page
            //
            // note: you can assign a specific call out accessory view, or as MKMapViewDelegate you can implement:
            //  - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control;
            //
            UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            [rightButton addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(showDetails:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

            return customPinView;

- (void)showDetails:(id)sender
{
  some code
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The comments in your code have the answer.  Instead of using a custom method and calling addTarget, use the map view's calloutAccessoryControlTapped delegate method.  In this method, you will get a reference to the annotation view which contains a reference to the annotation.

Remove the call to addTarget and replace your "showDetails" method with:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
    calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    MyAnnotationClass *annot = (MyAnnotationClass *)view.annotation;
    //do something...
}
```

Comment: but he wants to know among the many annotation which one was clicked!

Comment: @carbonr, `view.annotation` is the one that was clicked.  I'm suggesting to use the delegate method instead of addTarget.

Comment: @carbonr, if you must or want to use addTarget instead of the delegate, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9876255/467105