# Annotation details after detail disclosure pressed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

I have a MKMapView annotation object that has a right callout accessory detail disclosure button. When the button is pressed I am using addTarget:action:forControlEvent to call a selector method which creates a detail viewController and pushes it onto the view stack.

My question is what is the best way to access the information on the annotation that initiated the callout detail controller. The detail disclosure button is set to call:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(disclosurePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Which looks like this:

```
- (void)disclosurePressed:(id)sender {
}
```

I guess I could look for the parent annotation of the sender UIButton, can anyone give me any pointers to how this is best done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have an easier time using the `MKMapViewDelegate` `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` method, which tells you directly which annotation view was tapped.

Comment: Aha :) that sounds like just what I am after, let me give that a go. Much appreciated Nevan.

Comment: No problem. I forgot to mention that you can access the actual annotation through the `annotation` property of MKAnnotationView.

Comment: Thanks Nevan, have a lovely day.

Answer (score 3):

A reliable way (if you must use a custom method) is to look at the map view's `selectedAnnotations` property.

Though the property is an `NSArray`, since the map view only allows one annotation to be selected at a time, the one that the user just tapped will be at index 0 so it would be:

```
id<MKAnnotation> annTapped = [mapView.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0];

//Here, you can cast annTapped to a custom annotation class if needed.
//Be sure to check what kind of class it is first.
```

You may also want to first check that `mapView.selectedAnnotations.count` is not zero just to be safe.

However, a better way (as nevan king already answered) than using `addTarget` and a custom action method is to use the map view's `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method where the annotation is directly accessible through the `view` parameter using:

```
id<MKAnnotation> annTapped = view.annotation;
```

Comment: How can i get a number out of this? e.g if i want to get the ID# of the annotation to retrieve the appropriate content from an API etc

Comment: @carbonr, Hope that clears it up.  If still confused, suggest you [Ask A Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and include details of the problem.

Comment: Anna you are awesome! The previous links was the solution. What had happened was it threw an error when i was storing data in my custom class so i thought i was wrong, but i have figured it out